# Can't get changed property from attachPropertyChange

Tags: sapui5

I would like to know which property in the [JSON model](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel/overview) has changed when modified by a view.
For a test I took OpenUI5 walkthrough [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.databinding.15/preview) and added the following lines in the application controller

```
oProductModel.attachPropertyChange( function(oEvent){
   console.log("event: ", oEvent);
}, this);
```

When I change a property in the text input, the function in the attachPropertyChange is called but oEvent object is empty as I print it in console.

I know I could connect to text input change event, but I would like to use attachPropertyChange in case there would be multiple views of the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you'd like to avoid using the `change` event of the Input control because there is no information about which property in the model has changed. However, you can still get all the relevant information within the change handler via:

- `oControl.getBinding(/*controlPropertyName*/).getPath()` to get the name of the bound property, or
- `oControl.getBindingContext(/*modelName*/).getPath(/*suffix*/)` to get the path of the bound context. The `getPath` here awaits an optional suffix that will be appended to the context path [with a `"/"` in between](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/9791563cb915b45565f09d8ee3b07021eedfd2c9/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/Context.js#L66-L74).

Combine those two APIs to get an *absolute path* in case the property binding was relative. E.g.:

```js
onInputChange: function (event) {
  const inputControl = event.getSource();
  const property = inputControl.getBinding("value").getPath(); // "myProperty"
  const absolutePath = inputControl.getBindingContext(/*modelName*/).getPath(property) // "/0/myProperty"
  // ...
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **change** event for all input field in UI, and write event handling method in the controller. You will get the property as well as value in the oEvent of the event handling method easily. I hope you understood.

Comment: I added change callback in xml definition (<Input value="{products>ProductID}" change="PrintEvent"/>), but event object in the callback PrintEvent does not contain information about which property in the model has changed.